# Create shader in code using Metal for .generateText on visionOS

Tags: swift, shader, metal, realitykit, visionos

I am trying to use Metal shaders to apply text effects to text made using `.generateText` on visionOS.
I am using the following UI code, and I am able to assign `SimpleMaterial` like this:

```swift
 RealityView { content in  
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 1)
        let resource: MeshResource = .generateText("Metal on visionOS", font: font)
        let entity: ModelEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: resource, materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .blue, isMetallic: false)])
        content.add(entity)
}
```

My problem is that I need to be able to create custom shaders using Metal. I know that I can use Reality Composer Pro, but I want to be able to create them in code using Metal shaders. I saw people do this using `CustomMaterial`, however `CustomMaterial` is not available on visionOS.
Here is a shader in `shaders.swift` file I am trying to attach to 3D text:

```c
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

[[ stitchable ]] half4 aqua(
    float2 position,
    float width
    ) {
        return half4(60.0/255.0, 238.0/255.0, 227/255.0, 1.0);
    };
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know `CustomMaterial` isn't available on visionOS so of course that won't work.

You will need to use a `ShaderGraphMaterial` with a `MaterialX` in `Reality Composer Pro`.

See [Explore materials in Reality Composer Pro](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10202/).